# Link directly to a piece of code in Visual Studio 2010 from the outside

Tags: visual-studio-2010, integration

I’m messing around with Code Metrics, and I wondered if it’s possible to create a link in an HTML page which will open Visual Studio, open the correct code file and jump to the indicated line?

I don’t mind jumping through a few hoops to get this to work.